# mpi4py Pickling error when trying to send classes

Tags: pickle, mayavi, mpi4py

im using mpi4py to split some calculations among several procs. Basically Im just calculating the volumes of some convex hull, which I create using tvtk and mayavi.

only the first proc imports These libs:

```
...
if rank==0:
   from tvtk.api import tvtk
   from mayavi Import mlab
   ...
   mlab.figure(size=(1024,768),bgcolor=(1,1,1))
   ...
```

Then, I try to share the objects mlab and tvtk among all procs:

```
for i in range(comm.Get_size()):
    comm.send(mlab,dest=i)
    comm.send(tvtk,dest=i)
....
```

The following steps would look something like...

```
Points=local_data
ug=tvtk.UnstructuredGrid(Points=Points)
...
dataname="Data %s " % rank
ds=mlab.pipeline.add_dataset(ug,name=dataname)
delaunay=mlab.pipeline.delaunay3d(ds,name=dataname)
... calc volume...
```

However, obviously its not possible to send instances/classes (or whatever mlab and tvtk are), as I always get the following error:

```
comm.send(mlab,dest=i)
File "Comm.pyx", line 753, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:53848)
File "pickled.pxi", line 122, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:20409)
 File "pickled.pxi", line 39, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.dump (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19503)
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

Is there any way to 'share' the instances mlab and tvtk among all procs?

EDIT: short example; can u get this working?

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD

size=comm.Get_size()
rank=comm.Get_rank()

if rank==0:
        from tvtk.api import tvtk
        from mayavi import mlab

if __name__=='__main__':
        if rank==0:
                for i in range(size):
                        comm.send(mlab,dest=i)
                        comm.send(tvtk,dest=i)
        else:
                local_mlab=comm.recv(mlab,source=0)
                local_tvtk=comm.recv(tvtk,source=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the following might work in your case

```
from mpi4py import MPI
MPI._p_pickle.dumps = dill.dumps
MPI._p_pickle.loads = dill.loads
```

Comment: For mpi4py v2.0.0 the required commands are `MPI.pickle.dumps = dill.dumps` and `MPI.pickle.loads = dill.loads`

Comment: For me the following error appears if I do that:
`AttributeError: 'mpi4py.MPI.Pickle' object attribute 'dumps' is read-only`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you cannot send packages in this way, you can import them though on all running instances though and use them where needed, which would seem to allow you to do what you want

This would not however share any global module data, which might be what you are trying to do so this would require you to send it around separately, and i would suggest using:

```
global_data = None

if rank == 0:
    global_data = {'value_of_interest': mlab.some_parameter}

global_data = MPI.COMM_WORLD.bcast(global_data, root=0)
```